# クラス継承でエラー　property does not override any property from its superclass

Tags: swift3

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]swift初心者です。クラスの継承をしようとするとタイトルのように怒られます
loadSCVクラスからnumberプロパティとdata配列を
step1クラスで使用したいのですが
numberは使用することができましたが、data配列は宣言エラーが出て使用できないです
ご指摘お願いします。
コードは以下の通りです

```
class loadCSV {
    let number = 32
    func loadCSV(){
        var data = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", count: number), count: number)

        if let csvUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data0112", withExtension: "csv") {
            do {
                let csvData = try String(contentsOf: csvUrl)
                let dataList = csvData.components(separatedBy: ",")
                if dataList.count > number * number {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
                for (n, item) in dataList.enumerated() {
                    data[n / number][n % number] = item
                    print(data[n / number][n % number])
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Not found CSV files")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class step1 : loadCSV{
    func step1(){
        var d = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", count: number), count: number)
        d = data
        let a : Double = 900.0
        let b : String = String(a)
        for i in 0...d.count{
            for j in 0...d.count{
                if d[i][j] == "0.0"{
                    d[i][j] = b
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### クラスの基本形

クラス定義の基本形を示します。

```
class クラス名 : スーパークラス名, 【準拠するプロトコル名】 { // カッコ内はオプション
    var プロパティ名: 型名 【= 初期値】
    func 【インスタンス】メソッド名(引数名: 型, ・・・) 【-> 返り値の型】 {}
}
```

クラスの基本構成物は、ほかにイニシアライザ、定数、クラスメソッド、タイププロパティ、タイプメソッドなどありますが、必要十分条件の必要条件は、プロパティと（インスタンス）メソッドです。ご提示のコード中のクラス`loadCSV`と`step1`いずれにも、プロパティがなく、それでコンパイルエラーになりませんが、クラスとは何か、何を目的にしているのかという、そもそも論を考えると、何も値を保持しないクラスは、蜜や花粉を巣に持ち帰らないミツバチと同じといえます。
※ここでいう**プロパティProperty**は、**インスタンス変数Instance Variable**と呼ぶことがあります。オブジェクト指向言語の多くで、インスタンス変数という用語が使われているので、そちらの方が通りがいいのですが、厳密には、プロパティとインスタンス変数は同じではないので、プロパティを使います。

---

#### 変数のスコープ（有効範囲）

変数には有効範囲があり、有効範囲をスコープと呼びます。そして基本として、ブロック（{から}で囲まれた、コードの集まり）がすなわちスコープになります。変数のスコープは、変数の寿命といってもよくて、プログラムの実行がブロックから抜けると、ブロック内の変数は解放されます。

```
func hoge() {
    var a: Int
    a = 200
    do {
        var a: Int
        a = 100
        print("Local a = \(a)")
    }
    print("Global a = \(a)")
}

hoge()

// "Local a = 100"
// "Global a = 200"
```

Playgroundで上のコードを書いて、実行してみてください。
ブロックは、関数（メソッド）、条件文、繰り返し文などで使われますが、独立したブロックを作ることもでき、その場合、Swiftでは、`do`を頭につけます。
関数`hoge`内で、変数`a`を重複して宣言していますが、コンパイルエラーにも、実行エラーにもなりません。それは、ブロックが入れ子になっており、`do {}`内の変数`a`の有効範囲がブロック内に限定されるからです。

```
func hoge() {
    do {
        let b = 300
    }
    print("b = \(b)") // Use of unresolved identifier 'b'
}

hoge()
```

ブロックの外で、変数`b`にアクセスしようとすると、「変数が定義されてない」とエラーになります。

ここまでで、クラス`step1`のメソッド`step1()`で、`d = data`の行でエラーになる理由がお分かりになりましたでしょうか？
変数をクラス内のどこでも使えるようにするには、プロパティとして宣言することです。プロパティとして宣言するということは、同時に、変数の寿命が、インスタンスの寿命と同じになることも意味します。（インスタンス外部からアクセスできる点もあり、大事ですが、ここではその説明は割愛します）

---

以下、ご提示のコードに改良を加えたコードを載せます。メソッド`loadCSV()`の実装を、イニシアライザに移動しています。この変更が、プログラム全体の設計の中で、妥当なものかは、私には判断できません。
それと、配列dataの要素の型を、`String`から`Double`に変更しています。これもご提示のコードの範囲だけで判断すれば、要素を文字列でなく数値にすべきだからです。プログラム全体の設計から判断したものではありません。

```
import UIKit
// import Foundation // UIKitがFoundationをインポートしているので、不要。

class LoadCSV { // 型名（クラス名含む）は、大文字で始めるという規則があります。
    let number = 32

    var data: [[Double]] // プロパティとして、dataを宣言。

    // イニシアライザ
    init() {
        data = [[Double]](repeating: [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: number), count: number)

        if let csvUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data0112", withExtension: "csv") {
            do {
                let csvData = try String(contentsOf: csvUrl)
                var dataList = csvData.components(separatedBy: ",")
                let listCount = dataList.count
                // dataListの要素数が、number * numberを超えた場合、number * numberを残して、はみ出した分は切り捨てる。「エラーと出力して終わり」ではさすがにまずいでしょう。
                if listCount > number * number {
                    dataList = [String](dataList[0..<number * number])
                }
                for (n, item) in dataList.enumerated() {
                    if let theNumber = Double(item) {
                        data[n / number][n % number] = theNumber
                    } else {
                        data[n / number][n % number] = 0.0
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Not found CSV files")
            }
        }
    }
}

class Step1 : LoadCSV{ // 型名（クラス名）を大文字で始める。
    func step1(){
        let a: Double = 900.0

        for row in 0..<data.count { // 後述
            for i in 0..<data[row].count {
                if data[row][i] == 0.0 {
                    data[row][i] = a
                }
            }
        }

// mapメソッドを使った場合。
//        data = data.map{ row in
//            row.map{ item in
//                if item == 0.0 {
//                    return a
//                } else {
//                    return item
//                }
//            }
//        }
    }
}

let obj = Step1()
obj.step1()
print(obj.data)
```

---

`Range`（範囲）の書き方の誤解があるので、質問と直接関係ありませんが、説明しておきます。
`Range`には、[CountableRange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countablerange)と[CountableClosedRange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countableclosedrange)があります。
`0..<32`は、`0 ≦ x < 32`で、`0...32`は、`0 ≦ x ≦ 32`です。使用を間違うと、out of rangeのエラーになります。

Answer (score 0):

data配列は、親クラスの関数 loadCSV　の中の変数であって、親クラスのプロパティではありません。
そのため、親クラスを継承しても参照することが出来ないのです。